# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns null - issue on writing or reading file?

Tags: android, bitmap

This is my code for saving a bitmap to sdcard:

```
public static boolean savePhoto(String fileName, Bitmap photo) {
    deleteOldPhotos();
    File sdCardPath = new File(MyApplication.getSDCardPathForPhotos());
    if (!sdCardPath.exists())
        sdCardPath.mkdirs();
    File destination = new File(sdCardPath, fileName);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this for retrieving it from sdcard and converting to Base64 string:

```
public static String getEncodedPhoto(String filename) {
    File photoPath = new File(MyApplication.getSDCardPathForPhotos(), filename);
    if (photoPath.exists()) {
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath.getAbsolutePath());
        setBugSenseExtraCrashData(filename, photoPath, photo);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] photoByteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        String photoBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(photoByteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return photoBase64;
    } else
        return null;
}
```

I've already searched the whole stackoverflow and found answers related to this issue, the problem is that the questions asked were reffering one static image/file. In my case, the system is in production and sometimes I get Bugsense telling me that `photo` object is null and a NullPointerException is thrown in `photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);` line. The file exists because it pass `photoPath.exists()`.

What could I have done wrong? The problem is in the save method or the load method? Any help or suggestions?

Comment: try using png instead of jpeg and see if it do any difference. I have faced  the same issue and fixed using png instead of jpeg.

Comment: I will try that! Do you think that I can get these photos that can't be decoded by other method(I mean sending them to my server)? I don't want the client to lose this photos. Thanks in advance.